# Is there an alternative to the T-Grip (Neuro grip) Isometric Stabilizer Power Push Up?

Tags: push-ups, grip-strength, grip

I heard some recommendations for using t-grip (Neuro grip)  especially for push ups. [image: t-grip (Neuro grip)][image: eush ups]. I would like to know what are the benefits in using it as comparison to regular push up. In addition, I would like to know if using a Tonfa in push up (holding it in similar way to shown in picture) can have the same benefits and a good alternative to  t-grip (Neuro grip)?[image: Tonfa pushup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know many other exercises you could do with these things.

As to benefits?

- A neutral grip (wrists straight and facing one another) position reduces a lot of wrist stress that people experience doing *normal* push-ups
- These handles can rotate on the small contact point on the floor, following along with the natural shoulder rotation. This doesn't necessarily occur with a normal push up, where the wrist is more locked in.
- The small surface area on the other end increases stability requirement.

A neutral grip can easily be achieved with a dumbbell or any number of push up handles [that you can grab for cheap online](https://amzn.to/2Wep9sR).

Some of those push up handles will rotate allowing for that natural shoulder rotation. Products like like the 'perfect push-up™️' but I believe there are many versions of this now. Not sure if their patent ran out or if there ever was one.

Anyway, as to the stability changes. This is a double edged sword. On one hand you'll get more stabilizer activation in the shoulders and likely core/torso. On the other hand, anytime you increase stability demands, you decrease power outputs and prime mover contributions.

These t-grip handles may be be nice as a change to mix things up if you already have good push up proficiency. But as a tool they do seem a little limited or one dimensional in what else they can do.

Whereas rings close to the floor would allow you do pretty much everything these do (shoulder rotation, neutral grip and increase stability requirements) and a little bit more (*chin up variations, dips, gymnastics moves like skin the cat, etc...etc...*).

You may also be able to find a rotating push up bar for cheaper and it will be more stable, which in my opinion is generally better most of the time. I'd simply train shoulder/torso stability more directly with other exercises. Easier that way.

> In addition, I would like to know if using a Tonfa in push up (holding
>   it in similar way to shown in picture) can have the same benefits and
>   a good alternative to t-grip (Neuro grip)?

As long as you have two of those things, it should be kinda similar. Or it could be similar to using just one, with your other hand on the floor (increased stability). The long part of that bar may get in the way depending on how it gets used.

If you have one long bar attaching those two points of floor contact, you'd likely make things more stable. You would also be in a more pronated grip with less shoulder rotation if it's just a straight line from one shoulder to the other.